# If statement wrong argument, difference between .exists? and .any?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a model `link` if have an if statement: `<% if link.title == Link.any?(:title) %>` When I run this, I get the error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` I understand that this means that it means that it isn't getting anything for `Link.any?(:title)` But how do I fix this. If you don't understand what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm trying to make sure that none of the links I made have the same title as another.

On a side note, what is the difference between .exists? and .any?

Comment: `Link.any?(&:title)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enumerable#any?` takes a block and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the block returns a truthy value for any member of the collection:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

`#exists?` is an `ActiveRecord` method that returns `true` if one or more records matching a query exist:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class

So for your purposes, you might try something like:

```
<% if Link.where(title: link.title).exists? %>
```

Comment: Is there a way to return if two or three of them exist? Thank you for the help, especially the links.

Comment: You could use `#count`, like: `<% if Link.where(title: link.title).count >= 2 %>`